# Cannot get ng-bootstrap component to work outside app.component

Tags: bootstrap-5, ng-bootstrap, angular15

I'm facing an issue when working with ng-bootstrap widgets in my angular app.

I'm using angular 15 and ng-bootstrap 14 as shown below:

```
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1501.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular   15.1.6
@angular-devkit/core            15.1.6
@angular-devkit/schematics      15.1.6
@angular/cli                    15.1.6
@schematics/angular             15.1.6
rxjs                            7.8.0
typescript                      4.9.5
```

```
dependencies on package.json:

    "@angular/animations": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.1.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^14.0.1",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
```

The problem I have is that I'm importing NgbModule on my app.module.ts as suggested on ng-bootstrap getting started section (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started) but the widgets such as ngb-accordion only seem to work within my app.component.html and I cannot get it to work on any other component. The code I tried so far is as follows:

```
app.module.ts:

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  exports:[NgbModule]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And the error it gives when compiling is:

```
Error: src/components/bootstrap-components/accordion/accordion.component.html:38:1 - error NG8001: 'ngb-accordion' is not a known element:
1. If 'ngb-accordion' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngb-accordion' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

I tried putting the accordion in my app.component html and it works nicely but on any other component it does not.

What I also tried and did work is mark the AccordionComponent (of my project) as standalone and adding NgbModule in its imports array, but I don't think having to make all my components standalone for it to work is a good solution.

I did not post the entire code of the component to make this post more readable, but the full code of the project can be downloaded here: https://gitlab.com/arendevel/bootstrap-pwrd-angular

As suggested by @Pieterjan I added a module and there I imported NgbAccordionModule, now VS Code does not give me error but compiling with ng serve does:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BootstrapAccordionComponent } from './bootstrap-accordion.component';
import { NgbAccordionModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NgbAccordionModule
  ],
  declarations: [BootstrapAccordionComponent]
})
export class BootstrapAccordionModule { }
```

[Compile error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W39vH.png)

Any suggestions?

Comment: What module declares (`declarations`) your `AccordionComponent`? That's where you need to import the `NgbAccordionModule`. That's how angular module dependencies work.

Comment: Could you please show me an example of what do you exactly mean? I'm new to angular as well and I don't really know how to make dependencies work.

Comment: Look at what `NgModule` contains your `AccordionComponent`. There you need to add the `NgbAccordionModule` to its `imports` array

Comment: My accordion component does not have any NgModule, I just have one NgModule and it's the app.component's.

Comment: I added an accordion module and there imported NgbModule and also tried to import NgbAccordion itself and VS code now does not print compile error but ng serve does. What else can I do?